# Show that if $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ then $\forall n, n > ab~\exists \ x,y \in \mathbb{N} : n = ax + by$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

The question is the exercise 27 Chapter 1 of the book Analytic Number Theory by Apostle:

> For $a,b \in \mathbb{N} $ show that
>
> **a.** If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ then for every $n > ab$ there exist positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $n = ax + by$.
>
> **b.** If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ there are no positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ab = ax + by$.

I don't know how to solve this problem. By induction it fails to be approachable: For $n=1$, suppose $ab+1=ax+by$. But $ab+1=a(b-a)+a^2+1$ and $a^2+1=by?$

Comment: Do you know about Bezout's identity?

Comment: @shardulc, $ax + by = \gcd(a, b)$ is for $x$ and $y$ to be integers not limited to positive integers. Besides, In this exercise $\gcd(a, b)=1$ not by the question is for $>ab>1$.

Comment: it is clear that if a and b are both negative the question a) is
false as ax + by is negative for positive x and y.

If a and b are both positive the question b) is false, take x as
half of b
  and  y as the half of a.

Comment: @m.idaya, thanks I edited according to the book. btw, half of a or b; what if a or b is odd? if both even then (a,b)>1

Comment: sorry for the issue b) I was fast you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(x_0,y_0)$ is any particular solution of the linear Diophantine equation $ax+by=n$ (such a solution is indeed exist since $\gcd(a,b)=1$), then 
$$
\left(x_0+\frac{b}{d}t\,,\,y_0-\frac{a}{d}t\right),
$$
where $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and $t$ is an arbitrary integer, are all its solutions. Now, we need to prove that there exist an integer $t$ such that 
$$
x_0+\frac{b}{d}t>0\quad\hbox{and}\quad y_0-\frac{a}{d}t>0
$$
that is 
$$
(\ast)\qquad-\frac{x_0d}{b}<t<\frac{y_0d}{a}.
$$
Since $ab>n$, then
$$
\frac{y_0d}{a}-\left(-\frac{x_0d}{b}\right)=d\cdot\frac{by_0+ax_0}{ab}=\frac{dn}{ab}>d\geqslant 1,
$$
so the interval $(\ast)$ defiantly contains a suitable integer, as required $\blacksquare$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You can first prove: if $1 \leq n \leq a+b$, then there exist $x,y$ with $|x| \leq b$ and $|y| \leq a$ such that $ax+by=n$. 
This can be proved by considering the pair with minimum value of $|x|+|y|$. For example, if $x>b$ and $y<-a$, then the pair $(x-b,y+a)$ gives a smaller value.

Now this can be used to prove (a). For example, if $aX+bY=1$, with $X<0$, and $|X|<b$, then $ab+1=a(X+b)+bY$.

Comment: x, y, a, b are all positive integers. btw, I didn't get your answer :(